# I have a string, need that string to be compared with list of strings in TCL

Tags: string, compare, tcl

Need to compare string1 with string2 in TCL

```
set string1 {laptop Keyboard mouse MONITOR PRINTER}
set string2 {mouse}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use:

```
if {$string2 in $string1} {
    puts "present in the list"
}
```

Or you can use `lsearch` if you want to know where (it returns the index that it finds the element at, or `-1` if it isn't there). This is most useful when you want to know *where* in the list the value is. It also has options to do binary searching (if you know the list is sorted) which is far faster than a linear search.

```
set idx [lsearch -exact $string1 $string2]
if {$idx >= 0} {
    puts "present in the list at index $idx"
}
```

But if you are doing a lot of searching, it can be best to create a hash table using an array or a dictionary. Those are *extremely* fast but require some setup. Whether the setup costs are worth it depends on your application.

```
set words {}
foreach word $string1 {dict set words $word 1}
if {[dict exists $words $string2]} {
    puts "word is present"
}
```

---

Note that if you're dealing with ordinary user input, you probably want a sanitization step or two. Tcl lists aren't *exactly* sentences, and the differences can really catch you out once you move to production. The two main tools for that are `split` and `regexp -all -inline`.

```
set words [split $sentence]
```

```
set words [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $sentence]
```

Understanding how to do the cleanup requires understanding your input data more completely than I do.

Answer (score 0):

There is [`string first`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M8)

```
if {[string first $string2 $string1] != -1} {
    puts "string1 contains string2"
}
```

or

```
if {[string match *$string2* $string1]} {
    puts "string1 contains string2"
}
```